# MDX DdateDiff returns error "the currentmember function expects a hierarchy expression for the 1 argument. a member expression was used"

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

i have been struggling with this but couldn't figure it out. Basically, I want to calculate the difference in days between the departure date and the date selected from the date hierarchy. i tried the following two MDX scripts but both return the error i have in the title.

```
VBA!DateDiff("d",[Cruise Details].[Departure Date].member_value, TAIL(DESCENDANTS([Departure Date].[Departure Date].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember)).Item(0).member_value) 

VBA!DateDiff("d",[Order Details].[Departure Date].CurrentMember.member_value, [Date].[Hierarchy].[Date].CurrentMember.member_value)
```

any idea how to resolve this? thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution on the MSDN forums, not sure what the reason is behind why the above code in my original post is not working, but this works for me.

```
VBA!DateDiff

("n", // "n" = Return # of minutes between the dates

HEAD(EXISTING [Dim Extrusion Process Details].[Start Timestamp].[Start Timestamp],1).item(0).Item(0).MemberValue

TAIL( EXISTING [Dim Extrusion Process Details].[End Timestamp].[End Timestamp], 1).Item(0).Item(0).MemberValue)
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b2a65cdc-d455-49b8-a5a2-b856e18c0a69/computing-difference-between-dates-in-mdx